# d3.js: Rescale y axis of multiple svgs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have multiple SVG created via d3.js, all containing simple line charts.
Their y.domain goes from 0 to the max value:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.value;
})]);
```

Now I want to rescale all of them. So I want to use

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
}));
```

on all SVG charts by clicking one button.

I am pretty new to this. It would be awesome to get some advice, if this was understandable enough.